# finding the index of the min element in a list & getting element at the corresponding index position in another list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to find the index position of the minimum element in a list and print the element at the corresponding index position in another list.

For example:

```
?- min2(X,Y,[a,b,c],[5,3,7]).
X= b
y= 3
```

Code:

```
min2(A,B,[A|_],[B|_]).
min2(A,B,[X|T1],[Y|T2]) :- smallest(W,[Y|T2]),  % using a predicate to find the min element in the list
                           B is W,              % setting B to the result of above(i.e the min element)
                           min2(A,B,T1,T2).     % looking up position corresponding to min element in list1
```

the predicate for finding the min element in the list is:

```
smallest(Head, [Head]).
smallest(Element, [Head|Tail]) :- smallest(E, Tail), Head =< E, Element is Head.
smallest(Element, [Head|Tail]) :- smallest(E, Tail), E < Head , Element is E.
```

The result I am getting is :

```
X = a,
Y = 5 ;
X = b,
Y = 3 ;
false.
```

It somehow picks the first element also. My base case could be wrong? I tried altering the base case to `min2(A,B,[A|_],[B|_]).` and it breaks.

Please show me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you first write the fact `(A,B,[A|_],[B|_]).` it first returns the head elements of the 2 list. 
You need to trim the heads of the lists until the head of the second list is equal to B. As soon as you find that the head of list2 is equal to B, you need to return the head of list1.

Maybe you want to try this:

```
min2(A,B,[A],[B]).  %base case
min2(A,B,[X|T1],[Y|T2]) :- smallest(W,[Y|T2]), B is W, min2(A,B,T1,T2), !. 
min2(A,B,[H1|T1],[H2|T2]):- B=:=H2 -> A = H1 ; min2(A,B,T1,T2).
```

Couldn't try it (because im currently at work). But i think it should be smth like this.

Comment: thanks for ur reply.
I am getting `ERROR: =:=/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated`
What does B=:= H2->A actually do? =:= is numeric equality but what is -> ?

Comment: this is an if statement a -> b ; c  means that if a is true, then b else c. mmmh maybe wee need to use pattern matching instead of B=:=H2

Comment: oh and you need to write the second case i wrote after your second case. I think that's why it gives an error. sequence is that: my base case | your second case(predicate) | my second case(predicate).  Since B is instantiated in your predicate

Comment: So this is what I've got now with your base case ,my second case & your second case: 

`min2(A,B,[A],[B]).`
`min2(A,B,[H1|T1],[H2|T2]) :- minlist(W,[H2|T2]), B is W,
        B=:=H2-> A is H1 ; min2(A,B,T1,T2).`

It is throwing an error `ERROR: is/2: Arithmetic: `b/0' is not a function`

Am I doing it the right way or should I have your base case as a separate predicate?

Comment: you should have `min2(A,B,[A],[B]).   min2(A,B,[X|T1],[Y|T2]) :- smallest(W,[Y|T2]), B is W, min2(A,B,T1,T2).  min2(A,B,[H1|T1],[H2|T2]):- B=:=H2->A is H1 ; min2(A,B,T1,T2).
`

Comment: and i think you should put a cut (!) after the second case. so the second case is: `min2(A,B,[X|T1],[Y|T2]) :- smallest(W,[Y|T2]), B is W, min2(A,B,T1,T2),!.` Since (I assume) you want only the most minimum of the second list is to be calculated.

Comment: Yes I want only the most minimum. I tried with the cut, but I still get that `ERROR: is/2: Arithmetic: 'b/0' is not a function` . It means some type mismatch is going on?

Comment: ah i'm sorry i think this is because "A is H1". It should be A = H1 since H1 is a letter and not a number. As i said i can't try the code. sorry

Comment: Changing is to = works. I get it. 'is' is used only for numbers.
Thanks!

Comment: yeap is is used only for arithmetical expressions. it forces the rhs to be evaluated and that causes errors with letters.I updated my answer with the right code. if you tried that code and if it works you can accept my answer :D

Answer (score 0):

To give you little thing more, my definition of smallest in opposite order, like min_list:

```
smallest([A], A).
smallest([A, B|C], D) :- A > B, smallest([B|C], D), !.
smallest([A, _|B], C) :- smallest([A|B], C).
```

Simpler I think (and yours was also copy, not your own code). The corresponding predicate was, like I posted in DaniWeb:

```
corresponding(A, B, [A|_], [B|_]).
corresponding(A, B, [_|C], [_|D]) :-
    corresponding(A, B, C, D).
```

By combining these in self-obvious minimal rule, you get your min2 predicate. I mean that you are **way overcomplicating things**

Comment: It was not mine.. I had said I "found" a way to solve it :D I will continue discussion on daniweb.